# Ruby on rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, model-associations

i am doing a complex association and i have the following problem

i have 2 models. Custmer_bills and Billing_address and both have customer_ids in it. one customer has one billing address and one customer has many customer bills. assoication is as given below.

```
 class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :billing_address
    has_many :customer_bills
    end


    class CustomerBill < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :customer_id
    belongs_to :billing_address
    belongs_to :customer
    end

    class BillingAddress< ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :customer_id, :address, :city, :phone_work, :phone_home
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :customer_bills
    end
```

now with this association i am attempting billing address details like address, city, phone-no and displaying in `show.html` after the bill is created.

i made a belongs_to change in billing address and customer_bill i.e

i  have tried the following. in `show.html`

```
<% for billing_address in @customer_bill.billing_addresses %>  
    <strong>Billing Address</strong>  
  <%=h billing_address.address%><br/>

    <strong>City</strong>
  <%=h billing_address.city%><br/>
  <% end %>
```

there is no error in the above code but it does not display the details .

for this i had
 `has_and_belongs_to_many` association
and

```
<%=@bill.address%><br/>
```

and the above gives an error and corresponding code in controller

```
def show
    @customer_bill = CustomerBill.find(params[:id])
    @bill = BillingAddress.find(params[:customer_id])
  end
```

so how can i get the billing address details of a customer once the customerbill is made??

Seeking guidance. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relations in your view that don't correspond to the relations you've specified in your models, and querying the database using the wrong id parameters.

1. `CustomerBill` has `:billing_address`, **not** `:billing_addresses`. There is no need for a loop in `show.html.erb`
2. You're incorrectly querying `BillingAddress` using `params[:customer_id]`.  `find` for `BillingAddress` is going to search by the `:id` column, **not** the `customer_id` column.

Based on the information you've provided so far, `@bill` below is wrong and unnecessary.

```
def show
  @customer_bill = CustomerBill.find(params[:id])
  @bill = BillingAddress.find(params[:customer_id])
end
```

If `params[:id]` is the id value of a `CustomerBill`, you can get the `BillingAddress` from the `CustomerBill` instance without directly querying `BillingAddress.

```
def show
  @customer_bill = CustomerBill.find(params[:id])
end

# in your view
<%= @customer_bill.billing_address.address %>
```

Also, since `CustomerBill` only has **one** `BillingAddress`, there's no need for the loop

```
<% for billing_address in @customer_bill.billing_addresses %>  
  <strong>Billing Address</strong>  
  <%=h billing_address.address%><br/>

  <strong>City</strong>
  <%=h billing_address.city%><br/>
<% end %>
```

Can simply be

```
  <strong>Billing Address</strong>  
  <%=h @customer_bill.billing_address.address%><br/>

  <strong>City</strong>
  <%=h @customer_bill.billing_address.city%><br/>
```

Again, this is all based on the information you've provided. The way you're trying to use relations in your view does not reflect how your relations are setup in the models, so I'm making some assumptions about what you're trying to do *(since, for example, you never specified what this was a `show` method for)*.

Comment: I am sorry i haven't been clear on the issue. I wanted to retrieve billing address details of a customer after the bill was created. since `bill` and `bill_address` have a common `customer_id` field. i thought i can get billing address, city etc comparing customer_id of `bill` and `bill_address`. This is what i am attempting to do. Since there is no direct link between `bill_address` and `bill` i added the association to get details of that particular customer. i Hope i am clear.

Comment: The point is, `CustomerBill` **has** a `:billing_address` associated with it, so you can just use that directly. If you're wanting to get the `BillingAddress` of the `Customer` who owns the `CustomerBill`, you can just do `@customer_bill.customer.billing_address`. There's no need to do comparisons against customer ids from everything I've seen so far.

Comment: okay, i did not know we can use @customer_bill.customer.billing_address. Thumbs up for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer above. If you insisted on having BillingAddress as its own model instead of simply adding the billing address fields to Customer (this would eliminate a mess of confusion and headaches) then you could do this.. (this is assuming that the controller code above is the Customer controller)

Customer Model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :billing_address
has_many :customer_bills
delegate :state, :city, :address, :country, :to => :billing_address
delegate :bill_name, :bill_biller, :more_bill_attributes, :to => :customer_bill
end
```

Customer controller

```
def show
 @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
end
```

Customer View

```
<%=@customer.state%>
<%=@customer.city%>
<%=@customer.address%>
<%=@customer.country%>
<%=@customer.bill_name%>
<%=@customer.bill_biller%>
```

and so on... 
So 'delegate' will allow you to delegate calls to attributes and methods to another class in this case.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer, i had not thought about using `delegate` option. and to be clear i want the customer details in billing address in the Customer Bill view not the customer view. so based on your answer i have attempted this. and i am not getting the desired result. light on the matter would be good. i have posted the link in next comment :) Thanks again :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QrL3yxfw and just to be clear can we use delegate by some condition??? like `delegate :find_by_customer_id` or something similar to that?. i went through the few blogs about delegate and nothing like that was given about delegate with a condition.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks and plus 1 for the answer. :)